# Is there any way to restart gunicorn workers on error

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

Is there any way to capture a python error and restart the gunicorn worker that it came from?

I get intermittent `InterfaceError: connection already closed` errors that essentially stop a worker from processing further requests that require the database. Restarting the worker manually (or via newrelic http hooks) gets rid of the issue.

Stack is heroku + newrelic.

Obviously there's an underlying issue with the code somewhere, but whilst we try to find it, it'd be good to know that the workers are re-starting reliably.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the [`httpok`](http://superlance.readthedocs.org/en/latest/httpok.html) plugin for [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/) for that purpose. That would require you to use `supervisord` to daemonize your gunicorn processes though, but that [shouldn't be a problem](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html#supervisor).

Comment: Thanks - I forgot to mention this is hosted on heroku.. (have edited q)